# gcc and clang preprocessor doesn't understand L prefix

Tags: c++, gcc

Assume this code:

```
enum class Foo
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
};

#define HANDLE_FOO(f) case Foo::f: std::wcout << L#f << std::endl;
Foo x = Foo::Five;
switch (x)
{
    HANDLE_FOO(One);
    HANDLE_FOO(Two);
    HANDLE_FOO(Three);
    HANDLE_FOO(Four);
    HANDLE_FOO(Five);
}
```

msvc compiles it just right, but gcc gives this error: "'L' was not declared in this scope"

So, the question is: how can I workaround this thing? Not only 'L' prefix doesn't work, but 'u' and so on doesn't work neither.

This code compiles just fine, though:

```
std::wstring str = L"This is a string";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the anti-marco community is at times too militant. Prefer other constructs if possible but when a macro makes things easier use'em. I would consider using the local  macro idiom here though (#undef the macro when you've finished). EDIT: Ah, the motivating comment for mine just vanished:)

Comment: @Steve, yes, in the real code I undef it. It was written only as an example. Thanks :-)

Comment: If you happen to be using Boost or don't mind pulling in Boost.Preprocessor (which is independent), then it has `BOOST_PP_WSTRINGIZE`. It can make your life a little bit easier depending on your situation.

Comment: It is a bug in MSVC, after preprocessing there should be considered to be whitespace between all preprocessing tokens (even if there was not in the source), so `L#f` should behave like `L "foo"`  (not `L"foo"`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that construct is invalid, and MSVC should diagnose it.

The `#` operator "stringizes" its argument, so `One` becomes `"One"` -- but by preceding it with `L` you have two separate tokens, `L` and `"One"`.

What you want is a single token, the string literal `L"One"`. You need to use the `##` token-pasting operator as well as the `#` stringizing operator:

```
#define HANDLE_FOO(f) case Foo::f: std::wcout << L ## #f << std::endl;
```

Experiment shows that this works with both g++ 5.3.0 and clang++ 3.6.

Comment: note: token pasting works here because string literals (including the prefix) are *preprocessing tokens*

Answer (score 0):

Checked with `-E` option of GCC, a space was produced between `L` prefix and the string in your code and I guessed the space is harmful.

This code which uses `##` operator to concatenate the tokens worked:

```
#include <iostream>
enum class Foo
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
};

#define HANDLE_FOO(f) case Foo::f: std::wcout << L## #f << std::endl;
int main(){
    Foo x = Foo::Five;
    switch (x)
    {
        HANDLE_FOO(One);
        HANDLE_FOO(Two);
        HANDLE_FOO(Three);
        HANDLE_FOO(Four);
        HANDLE_FOO(Five);
    }
}
```